# Error massage on the phpmyadmin login screen

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

Today I installed phpmyadmin to use it locally with apache2 server on my linux mint 21 machine. However, on the login screen I get an error message that translated into English reads as follows:

There is a mismatch between the HTTPS protocol indicated on the server and client. This can lead to phpMyAdmin not working or a security risk. Correct the server configuration to correctly point to HTTPS.

Does any of apache2 users know which entry in the configuration is meant and how to correct it?

I've tried to looking the solution by myself but I failed.

Comment: This question might better fit on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ because it is not related to programming but about configuring your system. You should also copy&paste the original error message in addition to your translation because we can search in the translation files to find the corresponding English message or source location.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. That error was caused by one line in apache2 config file, which I've added when I was trying to solved one problem with executing php code on a server. It didn't helped but I left it as it was and I forgot about it. I remembered this when I was watching a tutorial about configuring apache2.